# Posting instagram carousel with python

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I want to post a carousel of n images using python. I have found various sources on how to upload a single picture with a caption by using libraries like InstaBot, but I could not find any source on how to do this with a carousel, if it is at all possible.

I have all the files stored locally and know how to get the filenames and everything within my script. I want to be able to set the order of the images as well. There tend to be 5 images, so the maximum of 10 will never be surpassed.

Anybody know if this is possible and if yes, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score -2):

as far as my knoledge no library has this option,But it is possible if u use API on your own

update: check instagrapi library

guys come on why -2 reputation, i am just trying to help as far as i know, i need reputation to comment on answers guys

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32710096)